# How do I get an ADLS Gen2 URI for my blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to create a Databricks external table that points to data sitting on ADLS, so I'm trying to figure out the proper URI syntax. Using [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction-abfs-uri), I've managed to get

`'abfss://file_system@mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/data-store/path/to/data/data/';`

But I'm confused as to what `file_system` is. Can anyone share/point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`file_system` is the name of the container inside your storage account.

You can always copy the blob address from Azure Portal

[image]

that has the form:

```
https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/file_name.extension
```

and then it could be easily converted (don't forget to replace `blob` with `dfs`, and `https://` with `abfss://`):

```
abfss://<container>@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/file_name.extension
```